# Input type "email" change to "text" when it is in :focus state

Tags: html, css, sass

So there is this problem that my input with the type of `"email"` change to type of `"text"` when it is in a `:focus` state. Also it adds  `kl_ab.original_type="email"` at the end of the input tag. This is problem for me since i want to have browser check if the address that user wrote is correct, so when type of `email` change to type of `text` writing first character makes it correct. To make a simpler picture i will post two screenshots from dev tools, one when email form is not focused, and second when it is in `:focus` state and code of course.

**UNFOCUSED INPUT**
[image: unfocused input]

**INPUT WITH THE `:focus` STATE**
[image: input with the :focus state]

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="#" class="form">
     <div class="form__group">
       <input type="email" class="form__input" placeholder="Email address" id="email" required>
       <label for="email" class="form__label">Email address</label>
     </div>  
</form>
```

**SCSS CODE**

```
.form {

  &__group:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }


  &__input {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: rgba($color-white, .5);
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    transition: all .3;

   

    &:focus {
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba($color-black, .1);
      border-bottom: 3px solid $color-primary;
    }

    &:focus:invalid {
      border-bottom: 3px solid $color-secondary-dark;
    }

    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: $color-grey-dark-2;
    }

  }

  &__label {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-top: .7rem;
    display: block;
    transition: all .3s;
  }

  &__input:placeholder-shown + &__label {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-4rem);
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like there's some JavaScript messing with your input. Sass and plain HTML won't help you here.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible because this project is plain HTML and Sass so there isn't single line of Javascript code.

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions, like password manager installed?

Comment: Yea you are absolutely right. I had kaspersky protection extension, i just disabled it and problem appear no more. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem and disabling Kaspersky will fix it but this is not satisfactory as my website users may have Kaspersky extension. I'll report but wonder how I can fix it now.

Comment: I had the same issue and disabling Kaspersky browser extension fixed it for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer to this question because The same happened to me as well

```
  kl_ab.original_type="email"
```

This attribute is added automatically at the end of the input tag because you have added the Kaspersky antivirus extension to your browser.

Kaspersky automatically adds `kl_ab.original_type=" email"` and change the input type from **email** to **text**.

Once you disable or remove the Kaspersky antivirus extension from your browser you won't face this problem.